# Pass form fields values from JS to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a custom Gutenberg block plugin containing a custom HTML form. In my block I have a init.php file, where I'm enqueueing a Google Maps API library. All the frontend of the map is in jQuery. Currently I'm using Axios to pass all the form fields values to GravityForms using the rest api, but that way I will have to expose my auth details.. Even though the JS is minified it's pretty easy to see the credentials.. So I'm looking for a way to pass all the fields values to my init.php file and create the form entry from PHP using GFAPI. What's the best approach to this?

Comment: The question doesn't fundamentally have anything to do with WordPress. Yes, you're using WordPress on your website, but the question comes down to how PHP and JS interoperate with each other. I'd recommend taking a look on the StackOverflow website for more general programming questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237673/how-to-hide-an-api-key-in-client-side-javascript) I found that relates to your question.